# git log Graph seems differences in GitHub and Console

Tags: git, browser, github, console

I merged my code from master to the master of parent repository by giving a merge request.
But see the difference in graphs

```
In console:
* 889abff Interlocation access
* ff76aab Quote added
* ddab77d Infrastructure updated

In gitHub (through browser)
* ee11223 Merge commit 'refs/merge-requests/110' of git://git.something.net/+everyone/..
  * 889abff Interlocation access
* ff76aab Quote added
* ddab77d Infrastructure updated
```

any idea ?

Comment: Is your local clone up to date with the github repo?

Comment: @knittl , local clone is upto date. The problem is with github. Its little slow :) Because I tried from another user's system. Still console shows correctly and github shows wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a common practice: do not fast-forward and always create a commit when merging (and is also default behavior for pull-requests on github, I suppose).

As [this post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) says,

> The --no-ff flag causes the merge to always create a new commit object, even if the merge     could be performed with a fast-forward. This avoids losing information about the historical existence of a feature branch and groups together all commits that together added the feature.

Comment: Yes it is. You are right. I had to wait for 1hr. After an hour it came as same !!!